# How to add sub query in SQLITE Android along with 'IN'?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

My problem is that I've to write this

```
select * from contacts where id in (select cpk from mapping where gpk = 'MY-VARIABLE-HERE')
```

Query in Android but it fails when its run.
When I run this with static variable it works and provide data but when I try this with selections args it fails.

So far I'have tried these:

**1)** `Cursor cursor = myDataBase.rawQuery("select * from contacts where id in (select cpk from mapping where gpk = "+"'"+"?"+"'"+")", new String[]{grpName});`

**2)** `Cursor cursor = myDataBase.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, "id in", new String[]{"(select cpk from mapping where gpk = '"+grpName+"')"}, null, null, null);`

**3)** `Cursor cursor = myDataBase.rawQuery("select * from contacts where id in (select cpk from mapping where gpk = ?)", new String[]{grpName});`

Please help me... Thanks in advance...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1925178/sqlite-query-using-nested-select check this if it helps

Comment: Thanks @Raghunandan but fortunately my query is working as expected the main challenge is to write this syntax in Android Sqlite query along with selection args...

Comment: Your option 3 seams correct. Why does it fail? (Exception? "Which?" : "No results?")

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I resolved this, i was passing the wrong value for variable.

```java
Cursor cursor = myDataBase.rawQuery("select * from contacts where id in (select cpk from mapping where gpk = ?)", new String[]{grpName});
```

Was working correct.

Thanks All for help.. :)

Answer (score 0):

do this pass in where clause

> "gpk = ?"

and in values array pass the values
like

```
new String[] {gpk_value}
```

Comment: can you please refine it more by adding the complete query... it will be more helpfull...

Comment: Please add some detail to the answer.

Comment: This does not work because parameter markers must not be quoted.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
String query="SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE id IN (SELECT cpk FROM mapping WHERE gpk = '"+grpName+"')";
Cursor cursor = myDataBase.rawQuery(query, null);
```

Comment: -1 This is very dangerous! Check [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: i know what sql injection is, but i am assume that data validation is not current question and agree that all data passed to query need to be safe.

Comment: This does not work because the strings are not quoted correctly.

Comment: @LS_dev SqlInject in Android who will play with your query if You are coding for Android device

Comment: @ErrorNo.2793985 Where comes `grpName` from? And if I create a group named `'; DELETE FROM contacts; --` in this application? SQL injection is traversal to any platform, it is only related with being lazy with user data. Also, if a created a group named `CD's`, it would crash this query and application.